# Cual es el objetivo de path y que dirección muestra en este bloque de código?

Tags: javascript, funciones, cookies

```
function setCookie(nombre, valor, expiracion){
            var d = new Date();
            d.setTime(d.getTime()+expiracion*24*60*60*1000);
            var expiracion = "expires"+d.toUTCString();
            document.cookie = nombre+"="+valor+";"+expiracion+";path=/";
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Las cookies solo son accesibles a la ruta especificada y a cualquier subcarpeta (subpaths) hija Por lo tanto, las cookies para la ruta "/carpeta/subcarpeta1/" no son accesibles para ruta "/carpeta/" pero si en los hijos /carpeta/subcarpeta1/*.

path '/' estará disponible para todo el sitio

[Cookie path and its accessibility to subfolder pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576535/cookie-path-and-its-accessibility-to-subfolder-pages)

Answer (score 1):

Las Cookies están relacionadas con el Dominio, toda solicitud enviada a un dominio que haya establecido una cookie llevará en las cabeceras HTTP esa cookie. La marca Path sirve para que solamente se envíe esta cabecera cuando solicitamos documentos dentro de dicho Path en el dominio que ha seteado dicha cookie.

Para una cookie con path=/es del dominio www.domin.io

- Si nos conectamos a www.domin.io/es/index.html si enviaremos la cookie
- Si nos conectamos a www.domin.io/index.html no enviaremos la cookie